# Clear Blockly workspace without moving items to trash

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, google-blockly

I would like to use code to clear a Blockly workspace, and in some cases overwrite with new Blockly XML. The issue I am facing, however, is that `Workspace.clear()` moves current items to trash, which can be annoying when trying to reset a workspace, or overwrite it with blocks (which means clearing it first, as otherwise the current blocks would be overwritten). I have found that I am able to clear the trashcan with `workspace.trashcan.contents = []`, but this results in some unexpected behaviour regarding the rendering of the lid, which appears slightly ajar despite it being empty.

Even if I could find a way to clear the trashcan, this would still result in clearing all *previous* items in there, while all I'm looking for is to do a **single clear action** without impacting the trashcan. I've tried looking at docs for [`Workspace.Clear`](https://developers.google.com/blockly/reference/js/Blockly.Workspace#clear), but they don't seem to give any semantic way to do this. I've also tried looping through [`Workspace.getTopBlocks()`](https://developers.google.com/blockly/reference/js/Blockly.Workspace#getTopBlocks) with [`Events.Delete`](https://developers.google.com/blockly/reference/js/Blockly.Events.Delete#run), but that also results in moving items to the trashcan.

I've also tried to implement a manual solution, something along the lines of:

```js
const contentsBeforeClearing = workspace.trashcan.contents_;
workspace.clear();
workspace.trashcan.contents_ = contentsBeforeClearing;
```

For the first line, I've also tried `Object.assign([], workspace.trashcan.contents_)` and `workspace.trashcan.contents_.slice()`, but in all three cases (including the top one), the end result is equivalent to simply calling `workspace.clear`. I'm guessing this is something to do with getter-setters manipulating `contentsBeforeClearing` (as the variable's value *has* changed if you test it in the console after the clearing to have the deleted block(s)), but how to get around that is beyond me.

How can I clear the workspace without **manipulating** (not just resetting) trashcan contents?

Comment: I don't have enough time to set up a test case, but does this code work for you?

const contentsBeforeClearing = workspace.undoStack_ ? workspace.undoStack_.slice() : [];
workspace.clear();
workspace.undoStack_ = contentsBeforeClearing

?

If not then my next inclination would be to try some XML-related shenanigans, but you might be better off making a feature request on the Github or asking around on the google group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/blockly)

Comment: @AmberB. thanks. Unfortunately, this seems to have the exact same issue: the bin still contains the items, and even though `contentsBeforeClearing` is both `const`ed and shallow cloned with `.slice`, the value appears to have mutated after running `workspace.clear()`: it seems that Blockly has some super-aggressive getter-setters in place. I'll try the dev forum: they've been pretty responsive in the past; I don't know why I didn't think of that this time. Thanks for the help!